# Traveling from Barbados Via USA and Canada

Tags: visas, transit, canada

We have an upcoming travel to Philippines from Barbados via USA, my friend and 1 have a B1/ B2 And C1. 
Question is we have a stop over in Vancouver for couple of hours, would it be a transit visa to Canada is applicable or needed for this itinerary?

Comment: Visa requirements depend on your nationality.  We cannot say whether you need a visa in Canada without knowing your nationality.

Comment: In particular, if you are Philippine nationals, you may be eligible for the Canadian [Transit Without Visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/without-visa/eligibility.html) program.

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: Hi Micheal, im carrying a Philippine passport and i have a B1/ B2 Tourist Visa of United States and my colleague has a C1 Visa.